# S3 bucket access is locked

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Its found that the S3 bucket in our account got applied with wrong bucket policy, now the access is denied for all users including root user

```
 "bucketName": "somebucket",
   "bucketPolicy": {
       "Version": "2012-10-17",
       "Statement": [
           {
               "Sid": "Stmt15348761457344",
               "Action": "s3:*",
               "Effect": "Allow",
               "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::dhasg",
               "Principal": "*"
           },
           {
               "Sid": "Stmt153478299578",
               "Action": "s3:*",
               "Effect": "Deny",
               "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::somebucket",
               "Principal": "*"
           }
       ]
```

We are not able to change the permission through AWS console and CLI and not able to delete the bucket also. How to fix it?

Comment: You're going to need to contact Amazon on this.

Comment: Did you try using your Root Credentials (not an IAM User) to remove the Bucket Policy? If that doesn't work, you'll need to contact AWS Support.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - tried with root credential from both console and cli. it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to edit the bucket policy as root.  You will not be able to delete the bucket, even as root until you modify the policy.

Comment: Or, you may need to delete the bucket policy, as the root user.